# Making `#!/usr/bin/env python` work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, msys

I use Bash on Windows, provided by MSYS.

I tried to run a Python file with a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to make this work?

I know I can launch the Python file by suffixing it with `python`, but I want it to work without the suffix too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned out to be a mismatch between Virtualenv's `activate.sh` file and MSYSGIT. It was never intended to work on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

Use the proper path where Python is installed instead, for example:

```
#!c:/Python/python.exe
```

---

If you have Unix-like path support on your system (I'm not familiar with MSYS), you can always enter the path to your `python` executable, i.e. the output of `which python`.

Comment: Or you could use `env`, as the asker is doing.

Comment: I can't change the shebang, it's part of a project which involves other programmers that work on Linux and Mac.

Comment: @RamRachum What's the output of `which env` and `which python` and `type python`?

Comment: Hard-coding the path to the interpreter doesn't seem like a very portable solution. I'd like this answer better if it considered whether there are more portable options (there may not be), and what the tradeoffs are.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in a [Python Launcher For Windows](http://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html)

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that spaces in shebangs are interpreted as supplying additional arguments to an executable, so `C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe` gets seen as `C:\Program` given `Files\Python\python.exe` as an argument.

The best solution for this, because Windows LOVES spaces in the `$HOME` directory and `Program Files` and other places even though it can really break things in cmd.exe and Powershell and other tools, is:

Install Python to `C:\Python` and add the `C:\Python` folder where `python.exe` lives and the `Scripts` directory that lives inside it to your `PATH` environment variable at the system or user level.

If you need Python 2.7.x and 3.x to co-exist, install them into `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python36` and `C:\Python37` and rename the `python.exe` to `python2.exe`, `python36.exe`, `python37.exe`, etc and add each of those folders and their `Scripts` folders into the `PATH`. You may want to determine which of the Python 3 versions you want to be the "default" and also make a copy in that folder as `python3.exe` to handle any scripts that use `!#/usr/bin/env python3`.

If your user home directory has a space in it, you may also experience issues if you use the `pip install --user somepackage` syntax. The `--user` defaults to your home directory, and the space will trip up things in this case as well. The workaround is described [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs) but boils down to exporting PYTHONUSERBASE to your environment.

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=/myappenv
pip install --user SomePackage
```

or in Windows (Powershell):

```
$env:PYTHONUSERBASE='C:\PythonPkgs'
pip install --user SomePackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Windows 10 supports installing Linux subsystems. If you run from there paths should be correct.

It should be a working solution if you are okay with running it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't answer the question...

For people that installed python2 then python3 and just now want their python3 programs to run... right-click => open with => Choose another app    now navigate to your python3 python.exe

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you run (from the shell):

```
$ /usr/bin/env python
```

..?

If it starts an interactive python session, then python can be found.  (You can also simply run: `type python`).   If it prints "no such file or directory", then `python` isn't being found in your PATH. See if the following can be tweaked to fix the problem (spaces in the path/to/python will probably cause issues):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/python
$ /usr/bin/env python
```